# Divide two strings to form palindrome

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given two strings, A and B, of equal length, find whether it is possible to cut both strings at a common point such that the first part of A and the second part of B form a palindrome.
I've tried bruteforce, this can be achieved in O(N^2). I'm looking for any kind of optimization. I'm not familiar with back tracking and DP. So, can anyone throw some light....whether i should think in these lines?

Comment: Are you looking for any such substrings, or for the ones which will form the longest possible palindrome ?

Comment: I think we should figure out the common index at which we should cut these strings. And resultant string would be same length as A and B.

Comment: `Cut the strings at a common point ....` => does that mean that the result is a single integer `i` such that `A[1..i] + B[i+1 ... j]` is a palindrome ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution considering that we cut the 2 strings in a common point. It runs in linear time w.r.t the string length, so in `O(n)`.

```
// Palindrome function
function is_pal(str) {
  str_len = len(str)
  result = true
  for i from 0 to 1 + str_len / 2 {
    if str[i] != str[str_len - i] then {
      result = false
      break
    }
  }
  return result
}
// first phase: iterate on both strings
function solve_pb(A, B) {
  str_len = len(A)
  idx = 0
  while A[idx] == B[str_len - idx - 1] {
    idx += 1
  }
  if idx >= str_len / 2 {
    return str_len / 2
  else if is_pal(A[idx + 1 ... str_len - idx - 2]) {
    return str_len - idx - 2
  else if is_pal(B[idx + 1 ... str_len - idx - 2]) {
    return idx
  else
    return -1 // no solution possible
```

The principle is the following:
First, we iterate on A, and reverse iterate on B, as long as they are 'symetric'.

```
A: aaabcaabb   ............    // ->  
B: ............   bbaacbaaa    // <-
```

If the strings are symetric until their respective middle, then the solution is trivial. Otherwise we check if the 'middle portion' of `A` or `B` is itself a palindrome. If it is the case we have a solution, otherwise we do not have a solution.